# Delphi TreeView: Can I have different styles in one node's text?

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-2010

I want to show a string like this as a note's text:

**Name:** John

It has a bold part and a regular one. Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using custom drawing ([`OnCustomDraw`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnCustomDraw), [`OnCustomDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnCustomDrawItem) events). Have a look at the CustomDraw demo that comes with Delphi. It demonstrates a custom-drawn treeview.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use owner-drawing. Have a look at the `On*CustomDraw*` events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom draw, yes, but this is not always handy. I can recommend looking at LMD ElPack (), namely their ElTree class. That class lets you use mini-HTML in nodes and optionally in secondary cells (ElTree is a TreeList control).

Comment: Hi @Eugene. Nice to see you here at SO. I bought ElPack from you many years ago, and I'm still using ElPack and ElTree (now ElXTree) in my application. It's a nice class. I've been tempted, but never had a need to move to VirtualTreeView, since ElTree has a Virtual mode of its own and does everything I need of it. LMD has been supporting it and producing new versions since they purchased it from you.